# iferror doesn't return value/error message

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup, importrange

So I have this function:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C825,IMPORTRANGE("gigduiagduaigiyug938y212hiugs","ApprovedVideos!A:G"),4,false),"Nil")
```

It doesn't work the way I want it to: If the cell is empty, returns 'Nil' and if it's not empty, just display the value that the importrange/vlookup returns.

What's wrong??

Comment: Do you have an example of how it has the wrong return?

Comment: Is there a typo in sheet ID?

Comment: @kishkin yes it's just a random id because i changed it from the original one which is a confidential file and i can't share it. i made an example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XVisgexKV6ri4uvTM_HpaJm_eprIW-BgNEeJHVk0GWQ/edit#gid=0

Comment: @a-burge the dates are imported from importrange via another sheet, so if there is no date in the other sheet, it will be empty hence showing the "Nil" or "No Info Found". Whereas if there's date imported from the other sheet, it will still keep the date as per imported and not show "Nil" or anything else.

Comment: It's impossible to see what is wrong without seeing the data. You can add the importrange formula in a separate tab in the document you shared to include the whole table.

Edit: Just looked at your example again. It's using C4 as reference in the Vlookup, that cell is empty....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C, 
 IMPORTRANGE("1oONnCRazwAwr3k2K0gc-tAT1SDLcBi2PnWAisXSzhtE",
 "VideoReport!A:G"), {5,6}, 0), 
 "No Info Found")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XVisgexKV6ri4uvTM_HpaJm_eprIW-BgNEeJHVk0GWQ/edit?usp=sharing

Here's the example sheet. I tried with the code i made yesterday it didn't work. IMPORTRANGE is authorized. What could be wrong?

Comment: can you share a copy of this sheet? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oONnCRazwAwr3k2K0gc-tAT1SDLcBi2PnWAisXSzhtE/edit#gid=0

Comment: I just shared it, sorry about that i actually forgot to share it :( https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oONnCRazwAwr3k2K0gc-tAT1SDLcBi2PnWAisXSzhtE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: thank you. but is there any way besides using array? We need to make changes and with array we can't :(
this is the error i got:
Error
Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in G2.

Comment: sure, try just this per row: `=IF(C2="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2, 
 IMPORTRANGE("1oONnCRazwAwr3k2K0gc-tAT1SDLcBi2PnWAisXSzhtE",
 "VideoReport!A:G"), {5,6}, 0), 
 "No Info Found"))`

Comment: This works well, except that it doesn't show the "No Info Found" Is there any way to make the message show?

Comment: try: `=IF(C2="" ,, IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2,   QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1oONnCRazwAwr3k2K0gc-tAT1SDLcBi2PnWAisXSzhtE",  "VideoReport!A:G"), "where Col1 is not null"), {5,6}, 0),   "No Info Found"))`

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for the help! You're very helpful!